# Use the Haskell monad "do" notation to define a syntax tree

Tags: haskell, tree, monads, abstract-syntax-tree, free-monad

I'm attempting to construct an abstract syntax tree that allows definition using the monad `do` notation like so:

```
ast = do
    Variable uint8 "i"
    Function Void "f" $ do
        Variable uint8 "local_y"
        Comment "etc. etc."
```

The construction I show here was gleaned from [Text.Blaze.Html](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/blaze-markup-0.8.0.0/docs/src/Text-Blaze-Internal.html#MarkupM), where it is used to define an HTML tree.

*Questions are scattered throughout the following. The main question is how to do this correctly. Any input that helps with understanding this construct is greatly appreciated, of course.*

So, first of all, here's a small, flawed, but 'working' example. It's a syntax tree with declarations of variables and functions of certain type, comment lines, and a placeholder declaration that is used for substitutions:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}
module Question
where

import           Control.Applicative
import           Data.Monoid         (Monoid, (<>))
import           Data.String.Utils   (rstrip)

type NumberOfBits = Word
type VariableName = String

data Type = UInt NumberOfBits
          | Int NumberOfBits
          | Void

uint8 = UInt 8
int8 = Int 8

instance Show Type where
    show (UInt w) = "uint" <> show w
    show (Int w)  = "int" <> show w
    show Void     = "void"

data TreeM a = Variable Type VariableName            -- variable declaration
             | Function Type VariableName (TreeM a)  -- function declaration
             | Comment String                        -- a comment
             | PlaceHolder String                    -- a placeholder with                  
             | forall b. Append (TreeM b) (TreeM a)  -- combiner
             | Empty a                               -- needed for what?

type Tree = TreeM ()

subTreeOf :: TreeM a -> a
subTreeOf (Variable _ _)   = undefined
subTreeOf (Function _ _ t) = subTreeOf t
subTreeOf (Comment _)      = undefined
subTreeOf (Empty t)        = t

instance Monoid a => Monoid (TreeM a) where
    mempty = Empty mempty
    mappend = Append
    mconcat = foldr Append mempty

instance Functor TreeM where
    fmap f x = x `Append` (Empty (f (subTreeOf x))) -- fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b

instance Applicative TreeM where
    pure x = Empty x
    (<*>) x y = (x `Append` y) `Append` (Empty (subTreeOf x (subTreeOf y)))  -- (<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
    (*>) = Append

instance Monad TreeM where
    return x = Empty x
    (>>) = Append             -- not really needed: (>>) would default to (*>)
    t >>= f = t `Append` (f (subTreeOf t))

indent :: String -> String
indent s = rstrip $ unlines $ map ("    "<>) (lines s)

render :: TreeM a -> String
render (Variable y n)   = "Variable " <> (show y) <> " " <> show n
render (Function r n t) = "Function" <> " " <> n <> " returning " <> (show r) <> ":\n" <> indent (render t)
render (PlaceHolder n)  = "Placeholder \"" <> n <> "\""
render (Append t t')    = (render t) <> "\n" <> (render t')
render (Empty _)        = ""

-- |In input tree t substitute a PlaceHolder of name n' with the Tree t'
sub :: TreeM a -> (String, TreeM a) -> TreeM a
sub t@(PlaceHolder n) (n', t') = if n == n' then t' else t
sub (Function y n t) s         = Function y n (sub t s)
--sub (Append t t') s            = Append (sub t s) (sub t' s)  -- Error!
sub t _                        = t

code :: Tree
code = do
    Variable uint8 "i"
    Variable int8 "j"
    Function Void "f" $ do
        Comment "my function f"
        Variable int8 "i1"
        Variable int8 "i2"
    PlaceHolder "the_rest"

main :: IO ()
main = do
    putStrLn $ render code
    putStrLn "\nNow apply substitution:\n"
    putStrLn $ render (sub code ("the_rest", Comment "There is nothing here"))
```

This is (should be) a really neat way to define complex tree structures. In particular, this should be the syntactically least noisy, user-friendly, way to define a syntax tree.

In general I struggle to understand the exact meaning of the `a` in `TreeM a`. The way I see it the `a` can be any of the types `Variable`, `Function`, `PlaceHolder`, etc.

I note a few things that strike me as odd:

1. In `forall b. Append (TreeM b) (TreeM a)` the order of `TreeM a` and `TreeM b`  arguments to `Append` seem to be reversed. In any case, the use of a existential quantifier in a sum type looks strange. If I understand this correctly, it defines a family of constructors for `TreeM`.
2. Of all the functions required by `Functor`, `Applicative` and `Monad` the only one actually used is the monad `>>`. (This indicates that a free monad might be the right tool for this job.) It actually never occurred to me that the do notation employs the `>>` operator and that this fact can be used.
3. An `undefined` has to be used in `subTreeOf` in order to make the function total.

As already noted, the example above is flawed: Parts of the construct are not appropriate for ASTs:

4. The definition of `Empty` makes sense for HTML trees, it is used for empty tags like `<br />`. But for the AST it makes no sense. It was left as is to keep the `Applicative` and `Functor` implementations working.
5. Likewise, the implementations of `Functor` and `Applicative` may make sense for HTML trees, but not for the AST. Even for HTML I don't quite understand the purpose of the `fmap` and applicative `<*>`. Both extend the tree by pushing down a node and adding an `Empty` type. I don't quite see which natural transformation on HTML trees that represents.

I'm surprised the `subTreeOf x (subTreeOf y)` in the definition of the applicative `<*>` is actually correct syntax, or is there an implicit `>>`?

#### AST transformations

It is natural to apply transformations on ASTs. The `PlaceHolder` serves as a little toy for applying a transformation. The function `sub`, having only a partial implementation, here, should substitute the placeholder "the_rest" with a comment. The necessary
`sub (Append t t') s = Append (sub t s) (sub t' s)` does not compile however, the expected type of `s` is `(String, TreeM b)`, the actual type is `(String, TreeM a)`.
Changing the type to 
`sub :: TreeM a -> (String, TreeM b) -> TreeM a`, on the other hand, breaks the definition of `sub p@(PlaceHolder n)` and now I'm stuck.

In fact, isn't this `sub` exactly what `fmap` for ASTs should be?

#### Free monad?

The term 'free monad' regularly pops up when monads for ASTs are discussed. But the free monad relies on the `Functor` `fmap` for the free construction and the `fmap` shown here is not adequate for ASTs. Once the correct `fmap` is identified the free monad should do the rest - maybe.

#### `fmap`

It seems that a correct `fmap` is the key for success here, and the correct `<*>` will probably become more obvious.

### Use-cases

**Loops** can be written with `forM_`, a nice way to build up repetitive parts of ASTs:

```
forM_ ["you", "get", "the", "idea"] $ \varName -> do
    Variable uint8 varName
```

**Conditional** parts can use `when`, `unless`, etc.

```
when hasCppDestructor $ do
    Comment "We need the destructor"
    Function NoReturnType "~SomeClass" $ do
        ...
```

**Semantic analysis**, e.g. ensuring correct declaration order, is also possible as was pointed out in the first answer.

**Visual clues**: Another thing I like is that in the construct shown above control structures such as if-then-else, `forM_` etc. start lower-case whereas the AST lines start upper-case.

### Background

A few words about where this is heading, possibly: The idea is to use a nice enough embedded DSL that allows to automatically define an AST that rather abstractly represents, say, a convoluted FSM that needs to be implemented in C, C++, Python, Java, Go, Rust, Javascript, whatever... A `render` function like the one above then maps the certifiably correct AST to the target language.

### Updates

- Note that `>>` does not default to `*>`, but to `m >> k = m >>= (\_ -> k)` !

Comment: For the desugaring of `do` notation, see [the Haskell2010 report here](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-470003.14).

Comment: When representing ASTs as a monad, the constructor `Empty` (as it's called here) corresponds to a hole (containing a temporary value), and `(>>=)` implements substitutions in those holes (where the new expressions can depend on the temporary values they replace). `(>>)` implements substitution by a constant expression.

Comment: `Append` is a trick to make "substitution" behave as concatenation. I'm not 100% sure this satisfies the monad laws but that seems to be the case (modulo some syntactic trivialities such as the fact that `Append` should be viewed as a monoidal operation).

Comment: `>>` does not default to `*>`!

Comment: @dfeuer `m >> k = m >>= (\_ -> k)`. Ok got it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this whole approach is a good idea (though, I've actually though a number of times of doing something similar myself).

Note that monads like `Blaze.MarkupM`, [`HaTeX.LaTeXM`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/HaTeX-3.17.3.1/docs/Text-LaTeX-Base-Writer.html#t:LaTeXM) etc. aren't really much of a monad. They're really just **monoids** that want access to monadic combinators (mostly, to abuse `do` notation, but it also allows stack monad transformers on top, which can make quite some sense). I.e., they're nothing but specialised [`Writer`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.5.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Writer-Lazy.html#t:Writer) monads!
At the moment, you're really doing the same thing; if that's what you're intending then maybe the best way to go about it would be to just design your type as a `Monoid Tree`, then look at the structure of the `Writer Tree` monad and, if desired, refactor it into a `TreeM` data structure. (HaTeX doesn't do this but keeps `LaTeX` and `LaTeXM` separate types with only a common class interface, which is arguably a cleaner approach, though it may be not optimal for performance.)

The result will be pretty like `Blaze.MarkupM` / the structure you have right now. I could discuss your individual questions, but really, they can all be answered by just looking at how the type is isomorphic to the writer monad.

---

Actually you don't need a `Monad` instance at all to use `do`, as such:

```
Prelude> 2 * do 1 + 1
4
```

So if you just want to abuse `do` to avoid parentheses in a tree layout, but don't really have a sensible way of stashing bindable variables in your structure, consider *not* writing any monad instance. That instance is only needed for a `do` block *with multiple lines*, but if none of these lines bind any variables then you can always just replace the implicit `>>` with an explicit `<>`, like

```
    Function Void "f" $ do
        Variable uint8 "local_y"
     <> Comment "etc. etc."
```

The only problem really is: these lines can't include the `$` operator, because that has lower precedence than `<>`. One nifty way to circumvent this is to observe that `($) = id`, so you can write your example as

```
ast = do
    Variable uint8 "i"
 <> Function Void "f" `id`do
        Variable uint8 "local_y"
     <> Comment "etc. etc."
```

Whether this is even more abuse of syntax than defining a not-much-of-a-monad instance is debatable. IMO, if you define such a monad instance you should right away make it a *monad transformer*, like `HaTeX` does, because that also gives the option to allow including `IO` actions in your AST build (for example, to hard-include external source files).

---

All that said: for your application, it might actually make sense to have a `Monad` instance that's *not* just a “sugared up monoid” but actually binds, well, **variables** in a useful way. That's a feature not applicable to `blaze`, but certainly to C++/Python/JavaScript language like ASTs, and it could be quite useful because it ensures variables are defined before use, right within the Haskell syntax. Instead of your example, you'd write

```
ast = do
    i <- variable uint8
    Function Void "f" $ do
        local_y <- variable uint8
        Comment "etc. etc."
```

The variables would under the hood then actually just be numbered identifiers, chosen according to a *state variable*.

Implementation would be roughly like this:

```
type VariableName = Int

data TreeS = Variable Type VariableName
           | Function Type VariableName TreeS
           | Comment String
           | PlaceHolder String
           | Append TreeS TreeS
           | Empty
instance Monoid where (<>) = Append

newtype TreeT m a
    = TreeT { runTreeM :: StateT VariableName (WriterT TreeS m) a }
    deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad)

variable :: Type -> TreeT m VariableName
variable typ = TreeT $ do
   i <- get
   lift . tell $ Variable typ i
   put $ i+1
   return i
```

Comment: Certainly, this is not much of a monad. Only the `>>` is used and that's a strong hint that from a computational point all that's needed is a monoid.
But to get at the 'do' notation I have to have a Monad, don't I? The 'do' notation achieves the goal (i.e. to succinctly define syntax trees) with the least syntactic noise, as far as I can tell.

Comment: With the right language extension, you can also use a form of `do` notation for arrows: https://www.haskell.org/arrows/syntax.html

Comment: @Davislor yes, but what has that to do with the subject here? The OP's type isn't even really a functor, much less an arrow.

Comment: It certainly is a functor; only the instance is a bit sketchy.

Comment: @dfeuer sure, but it is a functor _for the sake of enabling monad syntax_, not because it has any inherent functor semantics. The only way this makes sense other than for syntax-abuse is by combining these trivial monad semantics with other monads, i.e. by setting the whole thing up as a monad _transformer_.

Comment: With the monad other nice features become available, such as
`forM_ [1,2,3] (Comment . show)`

Comment: @leftaroundabout "Syntax abuse" - oh no no I certainly don't want to be guilty of that ;-) Joking aside. I'm fine with abusing syntax if it gives me what I want, i.e. an AST and a readable definition thereof without syntactic noise that carries no information.

Comment: `s/forM_/flip foldMap/`. — Sure, I myself use “unmonadic `do`” a lot. Just make sure you don't brick the option of using the syntax for stuff that actually is monadic, such as other monad transformers.

Answer (score 1):

The path I took with this `Append` encoding of the AST seems to be a dead end, so I dug deeper into free monads. Here's the result:

The [free monad](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/free-4.12.4/docs/Control-Monad-Free.html) is a good fit for this type of problem. Free monads allow to separate the 'logic' of a program from its effects. ASTs fall into this pattern. In this example the 'logic' is the AST and the effect is just pretty printing.

More generally, 'effect' can mean analysis, testing (dry runs, for example), running proofs, pretty printing, compressing, ..., and, of course, actual execution.

A lot has been written about free monads, here are a few useful resources to get started:

- ["Why free monads matter"](http://www.haskellforall.com/2012/06/you-could-have-invented-free-monads.html) by Gabriel Gonzalez
- ["What is the “Free Monad + Interpreter” pattern?"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/242795/what-is-the-free-monad-interpreter-pattern/242803#242803) (SE question)
- ["Navigating and modifying ASTs built on the Free monad in Haskell"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24172117/navigating-and-modifying-asts-built-on-the-free-monad-in-haskell)
   (SE question)

Now, using `Control.Monad.Free` a solution would look like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}
module Main where

import           Control.Monad.Free
import           Data.Monoid        ((<>))
import           Data.String.Utils  (rstrip)

type NumberOfBits = Word
type VariableName = String

data Type = UInt NumberOfBits
        | Int NumberOfBits
        | Void
        deriving Eq

uint8 = UInt 8
int8 = Int 8

instance Show Type where
    show (UInt w) = "uint" <> show w
    show (Int w)  = "int" <> show w
    show Void     = "void"

data AST n = Variable Type VariableName n                -- variable declaration
            | Function Type VariableName (Free AST ()) n -- function declaration
            | Comment String n                           -- a comment
            | PlaceHolder String n                       -- a placeholder with @name holds holds more code
            | End                                        
            deriving (Eq, Show, Functor)

end :: Free AST ()
end = liftF End -- is exactly Pure ()

variable :: Type -> VariableName -> Free AST ()
variable y n = liftF (Variable y n ())

function :: Type -> VariableName -> Free AST () -> Free AST ()
function t n p = liftF (Function t n p ())

placeHolder :: String -> Free AST ()
placeHolder n = liftF (PlaceHolder n ())

comment :: String -> Free AST ()
comment c = liftF (Comment c ())

indent :: String -> String
indent s = rstrip $ unlines $ map ("    "<>) (lines s)

render :: Free AST r -> String
render (Free (Variable y n next))   = "Variable " <> show y <> " " <> show n <> "\n" <> render next
render (Free (Function t n f next)) = "Function \"" <> n <> "\" returning " <> show t <> ":\n"
                                    <> indent (render f) <> "\n" <> render next
render (Free (Comment c next))      = "//  " <> c <> "\n" <> render next
render (Free (PlaceHolder s next))  = "PlaceHolder \"" <> s <> "\"\n" <> render next
render (Free End)                   = "end"
render (Pure r)                     = "return\n"

code :: Free AST ()
code = do
    placeHolder "includefiles"
    variable uint8 "i"
    variable int8 "j"
    function Void "f" $ do
        comment "This is a function!"
        variable (Int 8) "local_i"

sub :: AST (Free AST b) -> Free AST b
sub (Variable t n next) = do
    variable t n
    next
sub (Function t n f next) = do
    function t n f
    next
sub (Comment c next) = do
    comment c
    next
sub (PlaceHolder s next) = do
    comment "placeholder"
    next

main :: IO ()
main = do
    putStrLn $ render code
    putStrLn "-- Apply subst\n"
    putStrLn $ render (iterM sub code)
```

Not all of this needs to be spelt out so explicitly. Some of the boilerplate can be removed by using `Control.Monad.Free.TH`.

`Control.Monad.Free` is, in a way, the canonical implementation, but the chained data structure means quadratic complexity on some operations. This was addressed by the author himself, Ed Kmett, in `Control.Monad.Free.Church`, where a different encoding is used. See the [free monad benchmark](https://github.com/feuerbach/freemonad-benchmark) for benchmarks and pointers to other free monad implementations.

Going beyond free monads, cofree monads formalize the interpreter and its relationship with the 'logic'. See, for example, ["Free for DSLs, cofree for interpreters"](http://dlaing.org/cofun/posts/free_and_cofree.html) by David Laing.